# Finding area between two functions

Tags: calculus

Find the area of the region bounded by the two functions $f(x)=2$ and $g(x)=\displaystyle  \frac{x^2}{x+4}$.

My try:

\begin{align*}
\int_{-2}^4 2 - \frac{x^2}{x+4} \, dx &= \int_{-2}^4 2 \, dx - \int_{-2}^4 \frac{x^2}{x+4} \, dx  = 2x \big\vert_{-2}^4 - \int_4^8 \frac{u^2-8u+16}u \, du = 2x \big\vert_{-2}^4 - \int_4^8 u - 8 + \frac {16}u \, du \\
&= 2[(4)-(-2)]- \left. \left(\frac{u^2}2-8u+16 \ln |u| \right)\right\vert_4^8 \\
&= 12-\left[\frac{(8)^2-(4)^2}2-8\left(8-4 \right)+16 \left(\ln |8| - \ln |4| \right) \right] \\
&= 12-[-8+16(\ln|8|-\ln|4|)] = 8.909
\end{align*}

But when I'm kinda stuck, am I doing this right so far? Let me know please.

Comment: I think you want to change the limits in your 3rd expression, and also change the numerator to $u^2-8u+16$. (You could also use division in the 2nd term instead of substitution.)

Comment: like this? (see first line of my work)

Comment: I think you want to have 4 as the upper limit in the first term, and that you want 8 as the upper limit in the 2nd term (instead of 6).

Comment: Draw a graph of the two functions. Shade the bounded region for the clarity of your answer.

Comment: You have $d(x)=2-{x^2 \over x+4} = - { (x-4)(x+2) \over x+4}$, letting $u=x+4$ gives $\int_{-2}^4 d(x) dx = \int_{2}^8 (10-y - { 16 \over y}) du = 30 -16 \log 4 \approx 7.82$.

Comment: You need to work more carefully. When you substituted variables, you didn't compute the integration limits correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Euclid's algorithm for dividing polynomials to solve it in an easier fashion.

$\int\limits_{-2}^4\!2-\frac{x^2}{x+4}dx=\int\limits_{-2}^4\!2dx-\int\limits_{-2}^4\!(x-\frac{4x}{x+4})dx=\int\limits_{-2}^4\!(2-x)dx+\int\limits_{-2}^4\!(4-\frac{16}{x+4})dx=\int\limits_{-2}^4\!(6-x)dx-\int\limits_{-2}^4\!(\frac{16}{x+4})dx=[6x-\frac{x^2}{2}-16ln(x+4)]_{-2}^4=24-8-48ln2+12+2+16ln2=30-32ln2$